# Impact of hundreds of idle threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance, pthreads

I am considering the use of potentially hundreds of threads to implement tasks that manage devices over a network.

This is a C++ application running on a powerpc processor with a linux kernel.

After an initial phase when each task does synchronization to copy data from the device into the task, the task becomes idle, and only wakes up when it receives an alarm, or needs to change some data (configuration), which is rare after the start phase. Once all tasks reach the "idle" phase, I expect that only a few per second will need to wake.

So, my main concern is, if I have hundreds of threads will they have a negative impact on the system once they become idle?

Thanks.
amso

**edit:**
I'm updating the question based on the answers that I got. Thanks guys.
So it seems that having a ton of threads idling (IO blocked, waiting, sleeping, etc), *per se* , will not have an impact on the system in terms of responsiveness.
Of course, they will spend extra money for each thread's stack and TLS data but that's okay as long as we throw more memory at the thing (making it more €€€)

But then, other issues have to be accounted for. Having 100s of threads waiting will likely increase memory usage on the kernel, due to the need of wait queues or other similar resources. There's also a latency issue, which looks non-deterministic. To check the responsiveness and memory usage of each solution one should measure it and compare.

Finally, the whole idea of hundreds of threads that will be mostly idling may be modeled like a thread pool. This reduces a bit of code linearity but dramatically increases the scalability of the solution and with propper care can be easily tunable to adjust the compromise between performance and resource usage.

I think that's all. Thanks everyone for their input.

--
amso

Comment: If you need hundreds of threads, you're looking at the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Roger: I disagree, 100s of threads may be ok, depending on the problem. Using threads means that code can be nice an linear, which makes some tasks much easier.

Comment: I disagree with the disagreement. If you ever looked at `ps amx` output on Linux, you will notice some programs (like... `console-kit-daemon`) that keep around 63 daemon threads (of which 57 are generally useless and do nothing).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each thread has overhead - most importantly each one has its own stack and TLS. Performance is not that much of a problem since they will not get any time slices unless they actually do anything. You may still want to consider using thread pools.

Comment: Whether or not "idle" threads will use time slices depends on how their code is written. For instance, I saw a lot of "idle" code which just every several ms checks if it has to do anything.

Comment: Ouch :) Yes, by "idle", I meant a thread in a wait state, not "what the programmer thinks idle means".

Comment: By "Idle" I mean that the thread will block on a semaphore or wait condition until there is some outside activity that needs its intervention. For instance: a packet times out, received a packet, changed some data and need to synch...

Comment: @amso - exactly, that's the proper way to wait, and that will not steal any time slices. Still, I would try to not create too many threads if that's an option. Thread pools might be the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Chiefly they will use up address space and memory for stacks; once you get, say, 1000 threads, this gets quite significant as I've seen that 10M per thread is typical for stacks (on x86_64). It is changable, but only with care.

If you have a 32-bit processor, address space will be the main limitation once you hit 1000s of threads, you can easily exhaust the AS.

They use up some kernel memory, but probably not as much as userspace.

---

Edit: of course threads share address space with each other only if they are in the same process; I am assuming that they are.

Comment: the pthread library has a 32 megabyte per thread recommended minimum

Comment: Citation please; most systems I've seen seem to default at around 1M - 8M; I can't see where a 32Mb per thread minimum is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Linux hacker, but assuming that Linux's thread scheduling is similar to Windows'...

Yes, of course the will be **some** impact.  Every bit of memory you consume will potentially have **some** impact.

However, in a time-sliced environment, threads that are in a Wait/Sleep/Join state will not consume CPU cycles until they are awoken.

Comment: I believe that in recent versions, Linux threads are VERY lightweight.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library, and esp. the design paper that's referenced there.

Comment: @Steve I've read on numerous websites (and I think also in Understanding the Linux Kernel, though I may be mistaken on that one) that pthreads are implemented as processes on Unix, so it is actually rather heavy. Actually, your link says that as well now that I look at it.

Answer (score 2):

I would be worried about offering 1:1 thread-connections mappings, if nothing else because it leaves you rather exposed to denial of service attacks. (`pthread_create()` is a fairly expensive operation compared to just a call to `accept()`)

EboMike has already answered the question directly - provided threads are blocked and not busy-waiting then they won't consume much in the way of resources although they will occupy memory and swap for all the per-thread state.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. DoS is not a risk because threads are not created/destroyed based on incoming connections. Instead, they are created when one the application is configured (during its execution) to manage a new device and destroyed when a device is removed.

Comment: Could you examine my answer and let me know your thoughts? I think there may be an impact, depending upon the acceptability of latency in waking a thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning the basics of the kernel now. I can't give you a specific answer yet; I'm still a noob... but here are some things for you to chew on.

Linux implements each POSIX thread as a unique process. This will create overhead as others have mentioned. In addition to this, your waiting model appears flawed any way you do it. If you create one conditional variable for each thread, then I think (based off of my interpretation of the website below) that you'll actually be expending a lot of kernel memory, as each thread would be placed into its own wait queue. If instead you break your threads up for each group of X threads to share a conditional variable, then you've got problems as well because every time the variable signals, you must wake up _EVERY_DARN_PROCESS_ in that variable's wait queue.

I also assume that you will need to do some object sharing an synchronization. In this case, your code may get slower because of the need to wake up all processes waiting on a resource, as I mentioned earlier.

I know this wasn't much help, but as I said, I'm a kernel noob. Hope it helped a little.

http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/PrenticeHall/PrenticeHallPTRTheLinuxKernelPrimer/0131181637/ch03lev1sec7.html

Comment: My understanding of the NPTL implementation is that "every thread is a process" isn't half as bad as it initially sounds, because the clone call this maps onto is rather heavily optimised. Benchmarks seem to agree with this (http://kerneltrap.org/node/429). As far as one conditional variable per thread goes if it really was required and turned out to be a problem you can work around this by "hashing" (i.e. sharing) 1 cond var per 20 threads or so. I had been assuming that it would be IO blocking the threads not synchronisation primitives which I think is also cheaper.

Comment: Thread blocking is to be done using synchronization. Would a semaphore be a lighter solution? The waking and blocking of threads can be easily be modeled like a producer-consumer pattern.

Comment: Measure it and see. I think most of the pthread synchronisation primitives on Linux are implemented using futex(2) these days, so there probably isn't much difference between them. If they're not implemented using futex you might see some performance gains from using it yourself although I would strongly suggest measuring it.

Comment: @asmo If my interpretation of the article I posted is correct, I don't think a semaphore would be any lighter of a solution. As awoodland says, try it :). It may not be a problem at all in your case, despite the inherent shortcomings of Linux's 1:1 thread/process model.

Comment: @awoodland it appears that a futex has its own waitqueue anyway, so I'm not sure that the problem is averted. If every process must switch to the run state in order to see if it is ready to run, then you'll wake up a ton of threads each time you unlock the futex/semaphore in the case of a hash table.

Comment: @awoodland but then again, unless you're in a real-time app., I don't think waking up 100 (assuming 100 threads per futex, and 10 futex's) threads would be that big of a delay.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "device" you are talking about, but if it's a file descriptor, I'd suggest that you look at starting to migrate to using either poll or epoll (Id suggest the latter given the description of how active you expect each file descriptor to be). That way, you could use one process which would be responsible for all the fds.

Comment: Thanks. I think you misunderstood the question. I'm not polling events from a file descriptor nor anything of sorts. The question relates to the implementation of several tasks for the control of potentially hundreds of devices or entities, or anything that requires a stateful algorithm.