# Looking for architectures to develop massive multiplayer game server

Tags: language-agnostic

Hello all
Where can I find architectures and examples of building massive multiplayer game server
Does the does the concept of building it on top of libenevt is right ? or I need to think more 
on thread per connection ? im targeting to web players playing from flash / html5 clients .
Thanks

Comment: Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com if this doesn't get any answers.

Comment: Any platform requirements? Favorite programming languages?

Comment: c++ , linux , do what else , i also wander if libevent can fit in

Answer (score 0):

Well, for examples, the MMORPG [Ryzom is open source](http://dev.ryzom.com/). It is made of several C++ services (processes), some of which can run in multiple instances for scalability. The front-end services use UDP to communicate with the clients, while the inter-process communication is done using TCP and/or shared memory.

I have never used libevent but the concept sounds good. You probably don't want one thread per connection, for a "massive" multiplayer game, because running hundreds of threads is not recommended (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088892/impact-of-hundreds-of-idle-threads)).